Disabling bogus Google Chrome "compromised password" warning?
How do you turn off the nag popup in Google Chrome about compromised passwords?
I do a lot of local software web dev in Google Chrome, and for some reason, Google thinks the password for my local development server has been exposed.
What this means is that every single time I login to my local dev server, Google harasses me with a message like, "Your password has been compromised! Change it!", even though it's my dev server, which isn't externally accessible.
This password is also automatically set by devop automation tools shared with other devs, so I can't simply change it to some other junk password, which I'm sure Google will eventually start harassing me about anyways.
I also use unique strong passwords for all my real accounts, so this check and warning are completely useless. Besides, if I'm relying on Google to notify me of data breaches, then I've got much much bigger problems.
This help page claims there was once an option to disable this nag prompt at Three dots > Settings > Sync and Google services > turn off Warn you if passwords are exposed in a data breach, but it's no longer there in Chrome >= 122.
Is there some other way to disable this via a chrome:// page?

Is it possible for you to begin using a different browser? Google routinely moves settings away from options into forced "features" in Chrome, and once they do this there's not usually a way to get back to what you may want.

In my version of Chrome (127.0.6533.100) this can be disabled by visiting chrome://settings/security?search=breach and turning off Warn you if a password was compromised in a data breach
